# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany multiple "primary" keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In laravel I'm connecting events to users like this:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', EventUser::TABLE_NAME, 'user_id', 'event_id');
    }
}
```

which works great, but now I'm implementing repeat feature so I'm inserting repeating events for 2 years in the future in the database, and I don't want to make 1000 inserts, so I decided that I'll have parent event, and subevents will have parent_id in the database. Now the problem is that I can't get those events with belongsToMany, since I need to watch for 2 keys... id and parent_id.

Any idea how I can do that? I want to get events connected with user and events that have parent event connected with user.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function parentEvents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', EventUser::TABLE_NAME, 'user_id', 'event_id');
}

public function childEvents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', EventUser::TABLE_NAME, 'user_id', 'parent_id');
}

public function events()
{
    $parentEvents = $this->parentEvents;
    $childEvent = $this->childEvents;

    // Merge collections and return single collection.
    return $parentEvents->merge($childEvents);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to order events by custom key, and those 2 arrays need to be ordered with SQL, since ordering in PHP is bad for performance (huge amount of events). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: $parentEvents->merge($childEvents)->orderBy('custom_key');

Comment: That doesn't work, because parent_id is not in pivot table but in event table, so I need to somehow pretend that parent_id is actually primary key for 1 query and belongsToMany doesn't support defining primary key column.